# Editable but not changeable foreign keys in django admin

Tags: python, django

In Django admin, you can mark fields as readonly, including Foreign Key fields.

A regular ForeignKey field gets both a pencil to let you edit the current object being pointed to, and a dropdown/plus to let you point to another object.

I'd really like a ForeignKey field that has the pencil but not the dropdown/plus. That is, I'm fine with the admin allowing editing of the thing I'm pointing to, but not changing what I'm pointing to.

Is there an easy way to do this?